# is there a c++ library for ordinary differential equation (ODE) solvers?

Tags: c++, numerical-methods, ode, differential-equations

More specifically, i'm interested in 8th order Dormand-Prince embedded method, it's based on Runge-Kutta, and stiff equations.

I use Numerical Recipes 3 but i often have trouble compiling their libraries. I'd like to know of alternatives.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can also try [odeint](http://odeint.com). It has the classical Runge-Kutta solvers, Rosenbrock4 for stiff systems and some multi-step method. It is header-only, but you need the boost libraries.

Comment: Update: Odeint is now part of boost: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/numeric/odeint/doc/html/index.html

Answer (score 7):

The [GNU Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/) has several differential equation solvers.  They have one that uses [Prince-Dormand](http://www.gnu.org/s/gsl/manual/html_node/Stepping-Functions.html).  It's written in C so you shouldn't have trouble compiling it.

Comment: A small note: the DP stepper from GSL is explicit, and probably not that well suited for stiff problems with very different time scales. You may consider testing with an implicit method (GSL has some).